# How can I use a second keyboard as a Soundboard on Windows (remapping keyboard)?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I want have some Sound Effects ready if I'm on Discord or something, but don't have enough keys on my keyboard.
So my idea was to use a second keyboard and map the Sounds in Soundpad to my second keyboard.
The problem is, that the second keyboard will only be recognized as a normal keyboard and if I map i.e <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for a Sound in Soundpad, it will also be played if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on my main (gaming) keyboard.

Any idea how to do this?
I use Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Why don't you define additional shortcuts using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)? See https://www.autohotkey.com/#keyfeatures for more information.

Comment: @DavidPostill could you please explain how to do this with autohotkey?

Comment: AutoHotkey allows you to assign an action to a new shortcut. So you leave Ctrl+A as is and then assign Ctrl+Shift+A or Alt+A or whatever you decide (some currently unused combination) to play the sound. So you don't need the second keyboard.

Comment: yeah but my idea is to press a key on the second keyboard to play a sound while im playing or something (without pressing long shortcuts). I tried HIDMacros and nircmd, but it doesent work (if I open the .cmd file that I created, it plays the sound but if I say HIDMacros: If I Press i.e. <<A>> on second Keyboard than run application (my created .cmd file) nothing happens...

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: it should work with HIODMacros but dont (as described above) https://ibb.co/276bGQn
https://ibb.co/tsYGbZ5

Comment: ok seems to work except that HIDMacros reconigzed´´ my 2nd keyboard as a mouse...